# What is meant by parameterization?

Tags: data-driven-tests, parameterization

While reading one of the articles for Data Driven Testing, I came across a term 'parametrization of a test'. Could someone explain to me what is meant by parameterization here?

Comment: What is the article you are referring to?

Comment: Typically parametrization means fixing some parameters of a function or functional unit. In the context of data-driven-testing it probably means the process of defining parameters that are fixed and specifying their values. Other parameters are, in contrast, 'feeded' from existing data sources.

Comment: @Tim S http://ssofttesting.blogspot.in/2009/07/data-driven-test-or-parameterization.html is the article I'm referring to. I don't know QTP still I just went through it & came across 'parameteriztion'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see an example with TestNG. Suppose you have function `SomeClass.calculate(int value)`. You want to check the results the function returns on different input values.

With not-parametrized tests you do something like this:

```
@Test
public void testCalculate1()
{
    assertEquals(SomeClass.calculate(VALUE1), RESULT1)
}

@Test
public void testCalculate2()
{
    assertEquals(SomeClass.calculate(VALUE2), RESULT2)
}
```

With parametrized test:

```
//This test method declares that its data should be supplied by the Data Provider
//named "calculateDataProvider"
@Test(dataProvider = "calculateDataProvider")
public void testCalculate(int value, int result)
{
    assertEquals(SomeClass.calculate(value), result)
}

//This method will provide data to any test method that declares that its Data Provider
//is named "calculateDataProvider"
@DataProvider(name = "calculateDataProvider")
public Object[][] createData()
{
    return new Object[][] {
       { VALUE1, RESULT1 },
       { VALUE2, RESULT2 },
    };
}
```

This way, TestNG engine will generate two tests from `testCalculate` method, providing parameters from array, returned by `createData` function.

For more details see [documentation](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters-dataproviders).